# passing input from window.open to parent page

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a frameset, in which one of its frames open a pop-up using window.open . In that window opened i have a form to collect input from users. Input which i'm trying to return to the parent but failing to. Any help.
I tried using window.opener using this solution :[Popup window to return data to parent on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276086/popup-window-to-return-data-to-parent-on-close)
but failed to get the getChoice() outcome back to the parent page.

The frame:

```
<form>
<button type="button" id="opener" onClick="lapOptionWindow('form.html','', '400','200');">Opinion </button>
</form>
```

the frame js:

```
function lapOptionWindow(url, title, w, h) {
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
    return window.open(url, title,'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no,resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
}
```

form.html (the window opened):

```
<div id="lightbox">
            <strong>Chinese/Portuguese: Chinese<input type="radio" name="chorpor" value="" id="choice1"> Portuguese<input type="radio" name="chororpor" value="" id="choice2"></strong>
            </br><button type="button" id="food" onclick="getChoice()">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

form.js:

```
function getChoice() {
        var choice = ""; 
        var choice1 = document.getElementById("choice1 "); 
        choice = choice1.checked == true ? "Chinese" : "Portuguese";
        return choice;
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a proposal (I changed small things, please be careful):

Body of `parent.html`:

```
<button type="button" onclick="popup('popup.html', '', 400, 200);">Opinion</button>
=&gt;
<span id="choiceDisplay">No choice.</span>
```

JavaScript of `parent.html`:

```
function popup(url, title, width, height) {
  var left = (screen.width/2) - (width/2);
  var top = (screen.height/2) - (height/2);
  var options = '';

  options += 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no';
  options += ',menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,copyhistory=no';

  options += ',width='  + width;
  options += ',height=' + height;
  options += ',top='    + top;
  options += ',left='   + left;

  return window.open(url, title, options);
}

function setLang(choice) {
  var languages = {
      'en': 'English',
      'fr': 'French',
      'ch': 'Chinese',
      'por': 'Portugese'
  };

  var choiceMessage = 'You have chosen "' + languages[choice] + '".';

  document.getElementById('choiceDisplay').innerHTML = choiceMessage;
}
```

Body of `popup.html`:

```
<form name="f" onsubmit="sendChoiceAndClose()">
<fieldset><legend>Chinese/Portuguese</legend>

<p><input type="radio" name="lang" value="ch" checked>Chinese</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="lang" value="por">Portuguese</p>
<p><input type="submit" /></p>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

JavaScript of `popup.html`:

```
function sendChoiceAndClose() {
  var form = document.forms['f'];
  var choice = form.lang.value;
  opener.setLang(choice);

  this.close();
}
```

Here is a overview of the result:

[image]

So to give a short explanation, a JavaScript function defined in the `opener` window is called from the pop-up window to send back the choice information.

Be careful though, if the JavaScript called contains blocking code (for instance `alert(...)`), the pop-up will be closed only after the blocking code has finished (i.e. after the `alert` window has been closed for instance).

Comment: @dan what do you mean?

Comment: is it possible to open a chat for a couple of minutes?

Comment: It's not the very spirit of StackOverflow, but you can take a look at my profile to contact me if you need.

Comment: @maxime.bochon This is super cool. I pasted your code into 2 files, and it worked on the first try (on Chrome on Windows 10). Thanks!