# How to close popup window and pass the data parameter to parent window

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, popup

On page load I am opening a popup window for Terms and Condition. Once user will click on the accept button of terms and condition popup, I need to do some DB operation on button click once the operation will complete I need to close the popup and and show the parent window and on the parent window I need to pass the DB return value

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
        $.customDialogPopUp('Terms & Condition', '../Requisitions/TermsCondition.aspx', 95, 512);
    });
```

this is opening the popup. On button click of popup window

```
    protected void btnApproved_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
          // DB Operation...
          // var ReqId = DB return val
          //ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ClosePopup", "<script>CloseDialog1(); window.location.href =" + "../Requisitions/NewRequisition.aspx?ReqID="ReqId + ";</script>", true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I am struggling with line 3 of try block.

Comment: Someone please help me in this... :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32617334/470749 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have done almost same things, but guess it's a little stupid method.
In parent page, add below in javascript section.

```
function refreshByBtn() {
    document.getElementById('<%= btnApproved.ClientID %>').click();
}
```

In child page, add to javascript, too.
guess you might modify code below.

```
window.onunload = refreshParent;
function refreshParent(){
    self.opener.refreshByBtn();
}
```

When close child will trigger btnApproved_click() and then postback the parent page.